# some of the collection view cell didSelectItemAtIndexPath not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

I have been struck with this for a while. my error is for some cells in the time table didSelectItemAtIndexPath is not calling. i have kept a break point on the method and when i click for some cells the method is not being called. What could be the problem. Pls see the below code

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{

       return 25;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *) collectionView
{

          return 1;

}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"item clicked");
    CGRect rect = [collectionData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame;

    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController* vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"note"];

    pc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];

    [pc presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:collectionData
      permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                      animated:YES];
    NSLog(@" The index path is %@", indexPath);

}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    // we're going to use a custom UICollectionViewCell, which will hold an image and its label
    Cell *myCell = [collectionData dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TableCell"
                                                       forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.row < 20 || indexPath.row == 22 )
    {
    myCell.roomLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%ld,%ld}", (long)indexPath.row, (long)indexPath.section];

    NSLog(@"cell no %ld" ,(long)indexPath.row );
    myCell.subjectLabel.text =@"English";
    myCell.cellView.backgroundColor= [UIColor grayColor];

    [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if(isLongPressed)
    {
        [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet setHidden:NO];
    }
    else
    {
       [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet setHidden:YES];
    }
    }
     else
    {

        myCell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
      [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet setHidden:YES];
       myCell.cellView.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
      myCell.subjectLabel.text =@"";
       myCell.roomLabel.text = @"";

    }
    return myCell;

}
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Button");
    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Delete session" message:@"Do you want to delete this session" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have disabled user interaction of some cells dude.
check your code  below which is inside cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
else
{

  myCell.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // <-----Note this Line

  [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet setHidden:YES];
  myCell.cellView.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
  myCell.subjectLabel.text =@"";
  myCell.roomLabel.text = @"";

}
```

Comment: you are right but if i remove this line ie myCell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;  the below white cells ie at (20,0) , (21,0), (23,0) and (24,0) gets enabled.. i want only these cells should not have user intereaction...

Comment: i added a bit of code to this... i added  if (indexPath.row < 20 || indexPath.row == 22 )  to my didSelectItemAtIndexPath and it worked fine... thanks u r answer was useful to me

Comment: nandri bro... nice to see a Tamilan who has 14.5k reputation :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your greetings dude, but i hope we should discontinue this chat because out of topic will be considered as offensive in Stack Over Flow.